# Installing apk programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to find best solution for catch moment when user closed app installation menu.
If user press OK button and app was installed success, the intent PACKAGE_ADDED was sent but how to catch `CANCEL` installation button?

I think about some flags on `onStop`, `onPause` and `onResume` functions but I think it is not right way.

PS : Also If application has system permission
PSS: I think different workaround like abstract observer is not suitable.
May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor current top `Activity`, and check if it is installer `Activity`. Also register for actions like `PACKAGE_ADDED`, for monitoring installation progress. 
If user opened `PackageInstallerActivity`, then returned to `ManageApplications` activity, and you haven't received `PACKAGE_ADDED` action - then your application wasn't installed and that's the `Cancel` button action. That's all what you can do. There is no pre-install action sent by the system.

```
class MonitorActivities extends Thread{

boolean exit = false;
ActivityManager am = null;
Context context = null;

public MonitorActivities (Context context){
    this.context = context;
    am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
}

public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();

    while(!exit){

        // Return a list of the tasks that are currently running,
        // with the most recent being first and older ones after in order.
        // Taken 1 inside getRunningTasks method means want to take only
        // top activity from stack and forgot the olders.
        List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

        String activityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

        Log.i("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + activityName);

        if(activityName.equals("com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity")) {
            // User is currently in application installation process

            exit = true;
        } else if(activityName.equals("com.android.settings.ManageApplications")) {
            // user has been taken back to Manage Applications window
            // we should close the activity monitoring now
            exit=true;
        }
    }
    Looper.loop();
}
}
```